# Trouble reading an XML file in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, inputstream, assets

I'm trying to parse an XML file thru a DOM parser. However, I am having difficulty in getting my Main Activity to actually read the file. I've read that I should place the file in Assets and then called with getAssets(). I used something like this:

```
InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("myXML.xml");
```

This just results in an error: Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] device not found.

I've also tried new File("myXML.xml") using variations on the absolute path. Nothing seems to work. I'm getting a little frustrated. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

sounds to me, as if your IDE has no connection to the Emulator or device on which you are trying to test your app.

LogCat is a logging output stream that can be used by any app to print out informations /logs. And LogCat needs to be connected (via ADB) to your device.

If you don't have a real phone connected you can use an emulator:

```
/path/to/your/androidSDK/tools/android
```

this SDK manager helps you to create a new AVD (Android Virtual Device). Klick Tools>
Manage ACDs> New...

If you have a real phone or tablet connected to your computer, try restarting ADB 
(should be possible from within your IDE) or use the command line.

change to the directory where the Android  SDK is installed (in windows something like):

```
c:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\
```

on linux it could be:

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
```

then type (win and linux)

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I was using the emulator to run my app.